# How to create a 301 redirect that doesn't apply to subsites

Tags: redirect, htaccess, mod-rewrite

Scenario:

I'm trying to set a 301 redirect so that `https://foo.org/events` is redirected to a **non-WordPress** site `https://bar.org/events`.

On my `.htaccess` file, I set the following:

```
Redirect 301 /events https://bar.org/events/
```

This worked great until I found out the rule was cascading down to my subsites, which have completely separate and unrelated event pages. In other words:

- `https://subsite1.foo.org/events` -> redirected to `https://bar.org/events/`
- `https://subsite2.foo.org/events` -> redirected to `https://bar.org/events/`

[etc.]

But I don't want this. Again, those are completely separate event pages with unique content.

I only want the main site (`https://foo.org/events`) to redirect to `https://bar.org/events/`.

Subsite pages with `/events` in the slug **should not** redirect.

Please advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule` and `RewriteCond`) directive(s) instead, as opposed to a mod_alias `Redirect` directive, in order to check the requested `Host` header.

For example, try the following near the *top* of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section (the order of directives is important):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^events$ https://bar.org/events/ [R=301,L]
```

This redirects *only* `http(s)://foo.org/events` to `https://bar.org/events/` and ignores any other requested hosts, such as `subsite1.foo.org`. Note that the trailing slash is omitted on the source URL (as in your later examples), but included on the target URL. Your first example omits the trailing slash on both the source and the target URLs?

> **UPDATE:** The redirect should work whether or not there is a trailing slash

In that case, you should change the `RewriteRule` *pattern* to read `^events/?$` in order to match both `/events` and `/events/` and redirect to `bar.org/events/` in both cases. In other words:

```
RewriteRule ^events/?$ https://bar.org/events/ [R=301,L]
```

(Including the preceding `RewriteCond` directive as before.)

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing, since any erroneous 301 (permanent) redirects will have been cached by the browser. Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

Note that the `Redirect` directive is *prefix-matching*, so your previous `Redirect 301 /events https://bar.org/events/` directive would also redirect `/events/foo/bar/baz` to `https://bar.org/events//foo/bar/baz` (note the erroneous double slash). To replicate the same behaviour with the above `RewriteRule`, but less the double slash issue, you could change the `RewriteRule` directive to read:

```
RewriteRule ^events(?:/(.*))?$ https://bar.org/events/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This would redirect `/events` to `bar.org/events/`, `/events/` to `bar.org/events/` and `/events/<something>` to `bar.org/events/<something>`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Your suggestion works, however, you correctly pointed out the omitted trailing slash. My mistake in the criteria there. What edit should I make to the rule in order to fix this? The redirect should work whether or not there is a trailing slash.

Comment: In that case, you should change the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ on the first rule to `^events/?$`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!